# how can i enable both SPI for beaglebone black in QNX

Tags: beagleboneblack, spi, qnx

By default spi0 is available. It works fine.

Now I want both spi port works as dev/spi0 and dev/spi1.

I rebuilt the image after modifying the build file.

```
#######################################################################
## SPI driver
## SPI 0 ioport 0x48030100 irq 65
## SPI 1 ioport 0x481a0100 irq 125
#######################################################################
display_msg Starting SPI driver...
#  SPI0
#spi-master -d am335x base=0x48030100,irq=65,edma=1,edmairq=529,edmachannel=17
#  SPI1
# spi-master -d am335x base=0x481A0100,irq=125,edma=1,edmairq=555,edmachannel=43
spi-master -d am335x base=0x481A0100,irq=125
spi-master -u1 am335x base=0x48030100,irq=65
```

However, spi1 does not work.   only spi0 appears in the /dev folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out my problem.

I need to disable HDMI in order for dev/spi1 to work. What I did are the following two steps:

1, change build (bsp-ti-beaglebone-src/src/hardware/startup/boards/beaglebone/build) file in BSP. And rebuild the image

```
#######################################################################
## SPI driver
## SPI 0 ioport 0x48030100 irq 65
## SPI 1 ioport 0x481a0100 irq 125
#######################################################################
display_msg Starting SPI driver...
spi-master -u 1 -d am335x base=0x48030100,irq=65
spi-master -d am335x base=0x481A0100,irq=125
```

2, disable hdmi by adding the following line in uEnv.txt of the sd card

```
optargs=quiet capemgr.disable_partno=BB-BONELT-HDMI,BB-BONELT-HDMIN
```

If hdmi is not disabled while enabling spi1, the system crashes.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. How does 1 pin gets allocated to HDMI as well as SPI? You have to select the functionality using pinmux right? Could you please let us know how two controllers are connected to 1 pin simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something wrong with the command line. you missed the -d before the library. Please try -

```
spi-master -u 1 -d am335x base=0x48030100,irq=65
```

Comment: spi-master -d am335x base=0x481A0100,irq=125
    spi-master -d am335x base=0x48030100,irq=65
I tried -d for both spi as above.  Not working.  Perhaps I need to disable HDMI first.

Comment: "-d" is to specify the library name which contain the SPI transfer and configuration functions. So "-d" is must before "am335x" anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Still no /dev interface ? Also why have you come to the conclusion that you need to disable HDMI? why is that relevant here?

Comment: To Shaibal,    Thank you for your response.   I have tried "spi-master -d am335x base=0x48030100,irq=65".    And I still do not get dev/spi1 showing up. only dev/spi0 appears.

Comment: I have read that spi1 shares some pins with hdmi. So hdmi must be turned off for activating spi1